# How can I create a fixed-point filter of type uint8 or int16 using fdatool in MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab, signal-processing

I need to get the coefficients of a filter as `uint8` or `int16`. I use `fdatool` to create a HPF. When I choose the fixed-point option and export the coefficients they are still floating point.

Also, how can I choose the number of coefficients?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why fdatool doesn't output the integer coefficients but once you have the floating point coefficients you can follow the method described in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ug/create-an-fir-filter-using-integer-coefficients.html) to convert to the desired precision.

First, export the coefficients to MATLAB workspace, here I assume the coefficients are exported as variable `b`

---

For `int16`

```
signed = true;
B = 16; % Number of bits

bq = fi(b, signed, B);
L = bq.FractionLength;
bsc = b*2^L;

h = dfilt.dffir(bsc);
h.Arithmetic = 'fixed';
h.CoeffWordLength = B;
h.signed = signed;

% check results
all(h.Numerator == int16(h.Numerator))
fvtool(h);
```

---

For `uint8`

```
signed = false;
B = 8; % Number of bits

bq = fi(b, signed, B);
L = bq.FractionLength;
bsc = b*2^L;

h = dfilt.dffir(bsc);
h.Arithmetic = 'fixed';
h.CoeffWordLength = B;
h.signed = signed;

% check results
all(h.Numerator == uint8(h.Numerator))
fvtool(h);
```

---

The fixed-point coefficients are stored in `h.Numerator`.

---

To choose the number of coefficients set the "Filter Order" option in fdatool as shown in the following image. The number of coefficients is equal to one plus the filter order.

[image]

Comment: If I want to get vector of int16 then I need to use round(bsc) ?

Comment: Use `int16(h.Numerator)`

Comment: if I change true to false i still get negative numbers. why ? @jodag

Comment: @Alex if you set `signed = false` then you should be getting all positive numbers in `h.Numerator`. In the experiments I ran this was the case. Make sure you're using the most recent edit of the answer. I'm using MATLAB 2017a btw.